# Call RxJS flat map function only once per observable value

Tags: rxjs

I have a problem with a simple RxJS stream that processes some input, starts an Ajax request and processes the result of that request.

A simple example reproducing the problem:

```js
var requestCalled = 0;

function fakeRequest(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    requestCalled++;
    document.write("<p>"+requestCalled+" ("+value+")</p>");
  });
}

var stream = Rx.Observable.interval(3000)
  .debounce(500)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .flatMapLatest(fakeRequest);

stream.subscribe(() => {});
stream.subscribe(() => {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```

The result (calling `fakeRequest` twice per observable value)

```
1 (0)
2 (0)
3 (1)
4 (1)
```

The expected result (calling `fakeRequest` only once)

```
1 (0)
2 (1)
```

So I want that function `fakeRequest` to be called just once per value in that RxJS Observable. But when I add multiple subscribers, for each one the request is started.

Is there another method that can replace `flatMapLatest` so that only one request will be started for each Observable value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use `.share`

```js
var requestCalled = 0;

function fakeRequest(value) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    requestCalled++;
    document.write("<p>"+requestCalled+" ("+value+")</p>");
  });
}

var stream = Rx.Observable.interval(3000)
  .debounce(500)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .flatMapLatest(fakeRequest)
  .share();

stream.subscribe(() => {});
stream.subscribe(() => {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, that's great and it works. Thanks! Answer will be accepted soon.